# SSIS Script task get all the variable names and values

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis, custom-component

I need to parse through all the user variables in my ssis packages. As of now, I am able to get the names and values of ALL the variables in my package. I need to grab the name and the value and dump them to a table. As of now, I can display the name and the value through a message box, but I cant seem to figure out, how on script task I would be able to dump these values to a table. Any help will be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using System;
////using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
namespace ST_81ec2398155247148a7dad513f3be99d.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    public void Main()
    {


        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
        // Load a sample package that contains a variable that sets the file name.
        Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(
          @"C:\PackagePath\" +
          @"Template0719.dtsx",
          null);
        Variables pkgVars = pkg.Variables;
        foreach (Variable pkgVar in pkgVars)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(pkgVar.Name);
            MessageBox.Show(pkgVar.Value.ToString());
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output variable name and value in SSIS package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678365/output-variable-name-and-value-in-ssis-package)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how to get the list of variables, you could create a data source script component.