# execute package with .net and Job

Tags: ssis

is it possible to execute a Package with both a job and from .net?
how to change the input parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can execute the SSIS packages using [SQL Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141701.aspx) and from a [.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28096/Excecute-SSIS-package-DTSX-from-ASP-Net) application.

If you need to pass the input parameter then you need to use the SET option while executing through `DTEXEC` command line

```
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::YourVariable].Properties[Value]";"ValueToBePassed"
```

If you have several parameters to pass then you can use the above the query in a text file and then use the `CommandFile` option in DTEXEC

```
DTEXEC /File "C:\Package.dtsx" /CommandFile "C:\inputOptions.txt"
```

If your running from .NET .Add a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application`

```
using app=Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application;
string pkgLocation;
Package pkg;

DTSExecResult pkgResults;
pkgLocation = @"C:\SSISPackage\YourPackage.dtsx";
app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

pkg.Variables["VariableName"].Value = "VariableValue";
results= pkg.Execute();
```

Refer my answer in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695821/dump-ssis-user-variable-name-and-value-in-sql-server-table/11810453#11810453).I have used a script task to execute the package but you can use that code in your .NET app

Refer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx) article for further information